# How to find $n$-th value in a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

Let $(x_n, y_n, z_n) = (3, 1, 0)$ for $n=0$

For $n \ge 1$,

$$\begin{align}
x_n &= x_{n-1} +3 z_{n-1}\\
y_n &= x_{n-1} +2 z_{n-1}\\
z_n &= 5 y_{n-1}
\end{align}$$

Please let me know the formula to find $x_n,y_n,z_n$ values of any integer $n$.

The following would be the series:

$$\begin{array}{c:l}
n & x_n,y_n,z_n\\
\hline
0 & 3,1,0\\
1 & 3,3,5\\
2 & 18,13,15\\
3 & 63,48,65\\
\end{array}$$

Comment: What do you mean with $z$ on right hand are values of $n−1$

Comment: Let $X_n=(x_n,y_n,z_n)$. Then $X_{n+1}=AX_n$ for an appropriate $3\times3$ matrix $A$. So $X_n=A^nX_0$. Now if you can diagonalize $A$, you can find a formula for $A^n$, and, thus, for $X_n$.

Comment: The question has been formatted fantastically. Gerry I dint understand what you said, since it has been long time I learnt maths. If you explain more and derive the formula, it would be great. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Following Gerry Myerson suggestion, there is also a "hack". If $A$ is diagonalizable, then $x_n = k_1 \xi_1^n + k_2 \xi_2^n + k_3 \xi_3^n$, and you can find the polynomial $(z-\xi_1)(z-\xi_2)(z-\xi_3)$ by running the Berlekamp-Massey algorithm on the sequence of the first $x_n$s. Interpolation leads to finding $k_1,k_2,k_3$, too.

Comment: Or, by finding the characteristic polynomial of $A$, we have that $\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3$ are the roots of $p(z)=z^3 - z^2 - 10 z - 5$, hence: $$x_{n+3}=x_{n+2}+10 x_{n+1}+5 x_{n}$$ and the same recurrence relation holds for $y_n$ and $z_n$.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by GerryMyerson, you can rewrite your problem as
\begin{align}
X_n=A\cdot X_{n-1} =\ldots=A^nX_0
\end{align}
With $X_n =(x_n,y_n,z_n)^T$ and $X_0=(3,1,0)$, we only need the appropriate matrix $A$.

Your recurrence relation is 
\begin{align}
x_n &=x_{n-1}+3z_{n-1}\\
y_n &=x_{n-1}+2z_{n-1}\\
z_n &= 5 y_{n-1}
\end{align}
Or as matrix-vector product
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}x_{n-1} \\ y_{n-1}\\ z_{n-1} \end{pmatrix}
=
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 3\\ 1 &  0 & 2 \\ 0 & 5 &0 \end{pmatrix}}_{=:A}
\begin{pmatrix}x_{n-1} \\y_{n-1}\\z_{n-1} \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
Now we have to diagonalize $A$, i.e. finding matrices, such that $A=V D V^T$

Do you know how to proceed?

Comment: No. Could you please complete this. Please.

Answer (score 0):

By finding the characteristic polynomial of the matrix
$$ M = \left(\begin{matrix}1&0&3\\1&0&2\\0&5&0\end{matrix}\right) $$
that is $p(t)=t^3-t^2-10t-5$, and exploiting the [Cayley-Hamilton theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem), we have that:
$$ x_{n+3} = x_{n+2}+10 x_{n+1} + 5 x_n $$
and the same relation holds by replacing $x_{*}$ with $y_{*}$ or $z_{*}$. This gives an iterative method for finding $x_n,y_n,z_n$, and a closed expression too, in terms of linear combinations of the $n$-th powers of the roots of $p(t)$.

Comment: Jack, could you please complete this to find xn,yn,zn

Comment: The general form is $$ x_n = k_1 \xi_1^n + k_2 \xi_2^n + k_3 \xi_3^n$$ where $\xi_i$ are the roots of $p(t)$ (they are quite ugly to write down in a explicit way, just use the formula for solving third-degree equations) and the coefficients $k_1,k_2,k_3$ depend on the first three terms of the sequence.

Comment: @shariffbasha: numerically, we have: $$\xi_1=-2.34997,\quad \xi_2=-0.546111,\quad \xi_3= 3.89608.$$

Comment: It looks like these are approximate values. Below is the exact form solved using online calculator. Wondering this problem can be resolved.  x = 1\/3-1\/6 (1-i sqrt(3)) (1\/2 (227+9 i sqrt(835)))^(1\/3)-(31 (1+i sqrt(3)))\/(3 2^(2\/3) (227+9 i sqrt(835))^(1\/3))
x = 1\/3-1\/6 (1+i sqrt(3)) (1\/2 (227+9 i sqrt(835)))^(1\/3)-(31 (1-i sqrt(3)))\/(3 2^(2\/3) (227+9 i sqrt(835))^(1\/3))
x = 1\/3 (1+31\/(1\/2 (227+9 i sqrt(835)))^(1\/3)+(1\/2 (227+9 i sqrt(835)))^(1\/3))

Comment: @shariffbasha: yes, they were approximated values, I was just too lazy to write the roots and the coefficients $k_i$ in a explicit way. If you don't mind, why do you need the explicit formula? If you only need to compute some $x_n$, you can just use the given recursive formula $ x_{n+3} = x_{n+2}+10 x_{n+1} + 5 x_n $.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
x_n &= x_{n-1} +3 z_{n-1}\\
y_n &= x_{n-1} +2 z_{n-1}\\
z_n &= 5 y_{n-1}
\end{align}$$
$$x_n-y_n=z_{n-1}=5y_{n-2}\implies x_n=y_n+5y_{n-2}$$
$$y_n=y_{n-1}+5y_{n-3}+2z_{n-1}=y_{n-1}+5y_{n-3}+10y_{n-2}$$
You'll get solving recurrence relation:
$$y_n=f(n)$$
Then you'll get:
$$z_n=5f(n-1)$$
and 
$$x_n=x_{n-1}+15f(n-2)$$
from where again solving a recurrence relation you'll get:
$$x_n=g(n)$$